# How to Create Scheduled Events in MySQL by php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I can not use cron job so I need to use Scheduled Events but by php code

I need to insert to database on the last day of every month

I need to use only php code to create that Scheduled Event .

I read a lot but all must use mysql to can create it.

is there any way to do that by php code ?

```
$add_statics = "INSERT INTO statics (monthley_profits, monthley_total_products)
            VALUES ('$total_profits', '$total_products')";
            mysqli_query($link, $add_statics);
```

Comment: from where `$total_profits and $total_products` come from ? The event scheduler does not accept params hence its important to know the origin of those values.

Comment: $total_profits = $show_company['company_profits']; $total_products = $show_company['company_total_products'];

Comment: MySQL offers a built in Events system. When you use it, you can use php, or phpmyadmin, or whatever you want, to write SQL commands to create Event objects in your database. They'll run at an appointed date and time. Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html When you say "only php code" are you saying you cannot use the Events system?

Comment: I just want to create event by php file for example I create my database and tables by install.php , I need to create event by the same page install.php when I install my script for first time.